# Access icm20948-sensor data on raspberry pi 4 via chirimen-node-lib

Tags: javascript, typescript, i2c, raspberry-pi4

I'm using the [@chirimen/icm20948](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@chirimen/icm20948?tab=files) lib to read data from [icm20948](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DS-000189-ICM-20948-v1.3.pdf) motion tracking sensor on my waveshare [environment sensor hat](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Environment_Sensor_HAT) via i2c.

code:

```
  private mod!: any;

  constructor() {

    console.log('init');

    this.init().catch(err => console.log(err)).then(() => {

      console.log('initialized:');

      //read data
      setInterval(() => {
        this.read().catch(err => console.log(err));
      }, 2000);

    });
  }


  async init() {

    const i2cAccess = await requestI2CAccess();
    const port = i2cAccess.ports.get(1);

    this.mod = new ICM20948(port)

    await this.mod.init();
  }

  async read() {

    await this.mod.getdata()
    console.log("ACCEL: ", await this.mod.Accel);
    console.log("GYRO: ", await this.mod.Gyro);
    console.log("MAG:", await this.mod.Mag);
  }
```

output:

```
ACCEL:  [ 0, 0, 0 ]
GYRO:  [ 0, 0, 0 ]
MAG: [ -17790.75, 22288.75, 31548 ]
```

i can´t get the values for the accelerometer and gyro-sensor.

the getdata-function should update the sensor data.